# I am getting: Cannot call method 'someMethodName' of undefined when trying to access an object in a javascript clas

Tags: javascript

I am  almost new to JavaScript, and I am trying  to access an object within  a  class. This is my class definition in a file called analysis.po.js:

```
var AnalysisPage = function () {
    (some  code here)
    this.getSpousesCreditBureau = function() {
        return {
            pdScore: getSpousesCreditBureauElement('pdScore'),
            qualification: getSpousesCreditBureauElement('qualification'),
            estimatedFee: getSpousesCreditBureauElement('estimatedFee'),
            currentDebt:  getSpousesCreditBureauElement('currentDebt'),
            maxDebt: getSpousesCreditBureauElement('maxDebt'),
            arrears: getSpousesCreditBureauElement('arrears'),
            segment: getSpousesCreditBureauElement('segment'),
            bpGlobalRisk: getSpousesCreditBureauElement('bpGlobalRisk'),
            groupGlobalRisk:  getSpousesCreditBureauElement('groupGlobalRisk')
        };
    };
    (some other code here)
};
module.exports = new AnalysisPage();
```

This is the  piece  of code where I try  to get the object `getSpousesCreditBerauElement` in another file  called analysis.spec.js:

```
var App = require('../app.po.js'),
    Util = require('../util.js'),
    AnalysisPage = require('./analysis.po.js'),
    AnalysisData = require('./analysis.data.js');
(some code here)
var analysis = new AnalysisPage();
Util.verifyElementsAreDisplayed(analysis.getSpousesCreditBureau());
(some other code here)
```

The  error I  am getting is:
Cannot call method 'getSpousesCreditBureau' of undefined

Comment: Why did you fixed the code in your post, it was a typo? If not, let the original code for people to see what happened.

Comment: Since you are new to Javascript I would recommend reading [**You Don't Know JS: this & Object Prototypes**](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/this%20&%20object%20prototypes). In short Javascript does not have classes (yes there is syntactical sugar to mimic them) but you should learn how Javascript handles this. It will save you lots of headaches down the road.

Comment: Yes,  it was my mistake. I am really sorry.  It happened while trying a different approach, but the current code is the  one who gave me that problem.

Comment: In short, if you want instances of AnalysisPage to have the method `getSpousesCreditBureau()`, you need to define that method on AnalysisPage's prototype, not inside the AnalysisPage constructor. You'll do that like this: `AnalysisPage.prototype.getSpousesCreditBureau = function() { ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not actually exporting `AnalysisPage` and you're not calling it correctly.

---

Export the class with:

```
module.exports = AnalysisPage;
```

In comparison

```
module.exports = new AnalysisPage();
```

Exports an *instance* of the class.

---

The right way to call it is then:

```
var instance = new AnalysisPage();
Util.verifyElementsAreDisplayed(instance.getSpousesCreditBureau());
```

(Original question has been modified, code was:)

```
var analysis = new AnalysisPage();
Util.verifyElementsAreDisplayed(AnalysisPage.getSpousesCreditBureau());
```

---

You can export just the instance, in that case call it like:

```
var instance = require('./analysis.po.js');
Util.verifyElementsAreDisplayed(instance.getSpousesCreditBureau());
```

So no `new` anywhere.

Comment: I see OP has since modified his question.

Comment: Thank you it worked, and  you  have  clarified my doubts. Right now I am not able to  upvote your  answer, but I will do it in 6 hours.

Answer (score 1):

Did you tried:

```
var analysis = new AnalysisPage();
Util.verifyElementsAreDisplayed(analysis.getSpousesCreditBureau());
```

When you access the method like this `AnalysisPage.getSpousesCreditBureau()` you are not accessing the instance, but the class definition.